# Numpy arrays with elements as indices to other objects

Tags: python, numpy

The following script creates a RGB array from a colour-ramp contained inside a list. Elements of the array 'cabbage' are indices to the list 'cucumber'. The following script creates an array 'cauliflower' with the same shape as 'cabbage' but with the indices replaced with the corresponding tuples from 'cucumber'. Is there a more direct way in Numpy to carry out this procedure?

```
from numpy import array, shape, zeros

cabbage = array([[0,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,0]])
cucumber=[(0,100,0),(0,150,0),(0,200,0),(0,255,0)]
rows ,cols = shape(cabbage)
cauliflower = zeros((rows,cols),dtype=object)

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        cauliflower[row,col]=cucumber[cabbage[row,col]]

print cauliflower
[[(0, 100, 0) (0, 255, 0) (0, 200, 0)]
[(0, 255, 0) (0, 200, 0) (0, 150, 0)]
[(0, 255, 0) (0, 150, 0) (0, 100, 0)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy supports [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2):

```
>>> from numpy import array, shape, zeros
>>> cabbage = array([[0,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,0]])
>>> cucumber=array([(0,100,0),(0,150,0),(0,200,0),(0,255,0)])
>>> cucumber[cabbage]
array([[[  0, 100,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0, 200,   0]],

       [[  0, 255,   0],
        [  0, 200,   0],
        [  0, 150,   0]],

       [[  0, 255,   0],
        [  0, 150,   0],
        [  0, 100,   0]]])
```

Comment: That was my first thought - but it doesn't meet the requirement of being the same shape...

Comment: The shape may be (3,3,3) instead of (3,3), but it still impressed me! As it happens, my image array needs to be in 3d with dtype = 'uint8' for the PIL fromarray() function.